# Ubuntu 16.04 Suddenly Powers Off After Unplugging Charger

Tags: power-management, battery

I have a Dell Inspiron 7560 which I have bought very recently. I have dual-booted Windows and Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on it.

Ubuntu suddenly powers off after a few seconds of unplugging the charger (this does not occur any other time). The laptop is new and so is the battery so I don't see any reason for this occurrence.

Here is the output of `grep -i temp /var/log/syslog*` for help.

```
/var/log/syslog:Jul 12 02:59:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
/var/log/syslog:Jul 12 02:59:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog:Jul 13 00:38:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog:Jul 13 00:38:53 ubuntu sensors[971]: coretemp-isa-0000
/var/log/syslog:Jul 13 00:38:53 ubuntu sensors[971]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
/var/log/syslog:Jul 13 00:38:53 ubuntu sensors[971]: temp1:        +36.5°C
/var/log/syslog:Jul 13 00:39:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog:Jul 13 00:39:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 00:56:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 00:56:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:14 ubuntu ntpd[1060]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:15 ubuntu ntpd[1060]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:16 ubuntu ntpd[1060]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:17 ubuntu ntpd[1060]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:08:18 ubuntu ntpd[1060]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:16:40 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:17:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:18:00 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:18:00 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:28:40 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:29:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:29:34 ubuntu sensors[929]: coretemp-isa-0000
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:29:34 ubuntu sensors[929]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:29:34 ubuntu sensors[929]: temp1:        +45.0°C
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:29:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:29:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 01:43:03 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 09:57:58 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 09:57:58 ubuntu sensors[934]: coretemp-isa-0000
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 09:57:58 ubuntu sensors[934]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 09:57:58 ubuntu sensors[934]: temp1:        +35.0°C
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 09:58:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 09:58:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 10:12:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 10 10:12:34 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 12 08:14:16 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 12 08:14:18 ubuntu sensors[985]: coretemp-isa-0000
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 12 08:14:18 ubuntu sensors[985]: temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 12 08:14:18 ubuntu sensors[985]: temp1:        +34.5°C
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 12 08:14:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog.1:Jul 12 08:14:33 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
```

Comment: This really does smell like either a broken battery or a battery that is not working as it should.  Something to check: if you open BIOS and then disconnect the power supply you have a hardware problem if it turns off. "have bought very recently" You still have a warranty I would assume? Bring it back :)

Comment: Okay, so I just did that and it did **not** turn off. The BIOS also shows Battery Health as excellent. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, you can verify that the computer runs on battery by booting into windows, since it's dual boot (vs bios) which may be more intuitive (but achieves the same goal). If the battery/hardware is ok, open the Power settings in ubuntu (from GUI, just search for power, I believe; or, system settings, etc) and verify that it's not going to sleep after a couple seconds when unplugged (power management is configurable).

Comment: I checked the power settings and they seem fine. I've also unplugged the charger running Windows quite a few times and it runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have (at least for now) managed to solve the problem.

The problem, as far as I've been able to ascertain, was coming from Ubuntu using the Integrated Intel GPU instead of the Nvidia one.

After wiping my hard drive and reinstalling Ubuntu, I installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers and in `Nvidia X Settings/PRIME Profiles`, switched to the Nvidia GPU. The problem does not occur anymore (it comes back on switching to the Intel one).

UPDATE: Apparently, the problem wasn't solved. It is still getting powered off, and now even when I haven't plugged or unplugged anything.